# Sound conduction in a stethoscope

Tags: waves, acoustics, material-science, ultrasound

i am trying to build a stethoscope and since i have no idea about physics and acoustics i wanted to ask some questions, hoping Somebody can help me.

I mainly have some questions regarding the tubing and the stethoscope Bell, since i want to build a Bell only stethoscope.

1. What Is an ideal lumen size? Rather a large or a small one? (From 2mm - until 20mm)
2. What Lumen shape would Be ideal, oval or classic round?
3. the picture shows the tube of a manufacturer (MDF) that advertises that this Type of tube would conduct sound better than a normal flat Walled Lumen, would that be true????

For the Bell, i have the following questions:

1. Which metal would Be ideal? I thoight of Titanium?
2. Would there be a Better Bell shape than the Classic Ones? Perhaps with in internal design Like the tube from the picture? Ore a different rupe of Geometrie? In Order to pick up and conduct the sound better and with a Higher frequencies range?
3. If i would have a layer of gum on the outside of the Bell for a Better grip, would It influence the sound quality?
   I Hope you can help me, Greets :)

[image: questione Type of stethoscope Tubing, picture Is from MDF]

Comment: Hello Jamie Franklyn and welcome to Physics SE. It is considered best practice to ask one specific question per... question. This will help people provide good answers with one detail focused on one specific topic. Additionally, when you divide your problem into different focused questions "documentation" will be better since you'll have one "section" for each question/topic. I understand that this may be a bit more cumbersome on your side but I believe the benefits are worth the effort. Not only that but you can also link the other questions to each one and create a "network" for the problem.